# Why would you use a proto rule in a Perl 6 grammar?

Tags: grammar, raku

Here are two grammars. One uses a `proto token` and one doesn't. They both get the same done.  These are basically the examples in [S05 under "Variable (non-)interpolation"](https://design.perl6.org/S05.html#Variable_(non-)interpolation). In this simple example, they are both able to do the same things.

Which situations justify all the extra typing? The `proto` tokens have distinct methods in the action class, and maybe there's a small benefit there. However, you have to type some extra stuff to get that benefit.

Is there some feature of `proto` that makes other parts of the grammar easier?

```
grammar NoProto {
    token variable   { <sigil> <identifier> }

    token identifier { <ident>+  }
    token sigil      { < $ @ % & :: > }
    }

grammar YesProto {
          token variable      { <sigil> <identifier> }

          token identifier    { <ident>+ }
    proto token sigil         {    *     }
          token sigil:sym<$>  {  <sym>   }
          token sigil:sym<@>  {  <sym>   }
          token sigil:sym<%>  {  <sym>   }
          token sigil:sym<&>  {  <sym>   }
          token sigil:sym<::> {  <sym>   }
    }

class Proto::Actions {
    method variable ($/) {
        say "found variable: " ~ $/;
        }
    method identifier ($/) {
        say "found identifier: " ~ $/;
        }
    method sigil ($/) {
        say "found sigil: " ~ $/;
        }
    method sigil:sym<$> ($/) {
        say "found sym sigil: " ~ $/;
        }
    }

my $variable = '$butterfuly';

say "------No proto parsing";
my $no_proto_match = NoProto.parse(
    $variable,
    :rule<variable>,
    :actions(Proto::Actions),
    );

say "------Yes proto parsing";
my $yes_proto_match = YesProto.parse(
    $variable,
    :rule<variable>,
    :actions(Proto::Actions),
    );
```

The output shows that `proto` calls a different method in the action class:

```
------No proto parsing
found sigil: $
found identifier: butterfuly
found variable: $butterfuly
------Yes proto parsing
found sym sigil: $
found identifier: butterfuly
found variable: $butterfuly
```

Answer (score 11):

Technically, a `proto` will be made for you if you don't specify it yourself.  It basically creates the multi-method dispatch handler for that particular `token` (just as it does with `sub` and `method`).  Which you usually don't need to care about.

Why would you specify a `proto`?  I can think of a number of reasons:

1. because you want the `token`s to share some traits
2. because you want to execute some code before or after the dispatch

Yes, the `{ * }` may contain executable code.  The bare `Whatever` indicates the dispatching to the appropriate candidate.  Showing this in a simpler situation with `sub`:

```
proto a(|) { say "before"; {*}; say "after" }
multi a(Int) { say "Int" }
multi a(Str) { say "Str" }
a 42; a "42"
```

shows:

```
before
Int
after
before
Str
after
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Ah, okay. But why didn't the `sigil` method in the action class get called? I can see a use for this outside of grammars, but I'm trying to think up a case for it inside of grammars. The examples I've seen haven't been complex, or they've been cargo cult.

Answer (score 8):

Having the method it calls in an actions class can be useful for separating out the logic. It's basically the same sort of idea as multimethods except for grammars.

( I [wrote this](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#jVRNb9swDL3rV7BBOktp6nys2KFJnQE7D91ht6YDNEdujViWIclbiyL9650ky7JTZ0ANGLL4@EiRfHKtGPz5EqcrhB4k5ZxK@E71I@O0zCm8IAAt9qyEn7c/4Ph5Me865bvLIlc66QEHFFgtPGQlF@/CHbNO5RKVzbKm8qHmrNTJpmVVUmjhuaLqsybGAQJyrZ75mj1VScDZEM9oqoXMaZEYPBviUoi22heQQzxleRHw9ET8QgiZeLzol90WdlR2hCN4hYhER70@IMNLC6oUfKNFWhdUMzcszvSj2HXTwuMZcd3jdM9g3MWIOd0x18BACvk/QOpYYcQNC9ms/BnGkqm60HADyxVyxs7iwsTYG0hcUinFX8iEhK9OG57RpG@8VmiQtp8xz8w5gzK8MRRglNPkNA2reV4@YJhM@4SmMLJytAOwQrH/xfA@744zFJdvomNfJrAtp7Blth22syVMJsBg@Bz6Axkq8lTQfRv0bnIPxlDCJezhAhYQx/EvmJ8O2pPxqaDy6KR4MZPkAyftab8f9JO1m66fqq27DUcMZ2@UdkBvqv4NadA5hnEq7LjciLq/VVxRqZhHp3Bt2paLUuFwQwgQN0J0eKtkXuoMRufLuTpfNO@2HE3XLrJXqpkmSzWzeqxqDdFNBE9wNTfqtFI1FTGFm0PwWSNxR09M79Z3LJNpgcl9cuGgrZq49c6rygTzXy1i6SGjvSWN@X5jlpm7EfZatR7Goe@@2fS3ccY1HtmaRgTOziCKrGoVfYZXf0TvsbQe09Ba3MKkH2HaZV2Z1rHMauMKycKsC8ScVJApV6bmCz4jht2GuL3bYkZI44EyD8LNPw) for evaluating answers to a [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/104426/1147) )

```perl6
grammar Mathemania {
  token TOP               {   <cmd-list>           }

  token cmd-list          {   <cmd>+               }

  token cmd               {   <op>   <argument>?   }

  proto token op          { * }
  token op:sym<exp>       { e } # notice that the name doesn't have to match
  token op:sym<factorial> { f }
  token op:sym<root>      { r }
  token op:sym<ceil>      { c }
  token op:sym<floor>     { l }

  token argument          {  '(' ~ ')' <cmd-list>  }
}

class Calculate {
  method TOP      ($/) {   make $<cmd-list>.made   }
  method argument ($/) {   make $<cmd-list>.made   }

  method cmd-list ($/) {
    my $result = 2;

    $result = .made.($result).narrow for @<cmd>;

    make $result;
  }

  method cmd ($/) {
    if $<argument> {
      make $<op>.made.assuming( *, $<argument>.made );
    } else {
      make $<op>.made;
    }
  }

  method op:sym<exp>       ($/) { make -> \n, \e = 2 {  n ** e                   } }
  method op:sym<factorial> ($/) { make -> \n, \k = 2 {  [*] n, n - k + 1 ...^ 0  } }
  method op:sym<root>      ($/) { make -> \n, \r = 2 {  n ** (1/r)               } }
  method op:sym<ceil>      ($/) { make &ceiling }
  method op:sym<floor>     ($/) { make &floor   }

}
```

It also makes it so that a subclassing grammar can add its tokens along side of those that already exist, and a subclassing actions class can do the same. ( [try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#jVTbbptAEH3nKyaWU8AXHKdRH2wHt@pz1D70LU6lDR4cZNhFu9Amipxfb/fGzRApSAiYmXPmsnMoBcKfL0G0dpwDJ1lGONyR4gkzQhMCrw5AwY5I4dePn9C9XuW9ibL9PE1EEbYcJ6dGVe4@Kpye0XVRQ7lYrrJsCD@UGdIi3FaonLOCWSzL26iJDIDasxIv2Qaf87D2Y98fk6hgPCFpKP1x388Zq7p9Bd73R5iktT8a4E8Z46H1p@22q8Y6bbueC2/g@m5n1idH4qKUCAHfSRqVKSlQH1aGxRPbN6fljRe@nl5GjgjjhiPIyB71AGtQnf8DoAZVH7FBOSpr9gJjjqJMC7iF67WjjY1F0wSeNfgBJZyzvxAzDl/1bliESW@i1k4vbTtjEss6682wxroBuTkmpxxYmSX04MFk1gaYxvy1hp0AU4HvcdiYs3L6y2WHqNHzEHZ0BjtU41CTpTCZAEL/OrUPpL@RQ6THivR@8gDSQGEOR5jCEoIg@A1Xw6StNR4i5Z1KveWC@x@otLX7bdJPyi6nPtRbo4YOQtvNpp2aP9O3/R73kIjhX5SlJI8iNOIhffVRPEipKGnTtog08byRUvKOrs5YOiXnHOPkebWRI@z3WRXVQUijKuKfKB8hqtN5MI6Y2kadWFcW5IQLtI4ZrORCJIwK76xsH3y9opIy5wktYhhdXl@Jy6W5d3Q022hqq0S5rRgVqPSWlwW4ty48w82VVJ@SojwxFJ6pIlsYCWt4KHdjc48xj1JKPP8hnGrnTkz0897qRtLZt8qjCOqc6j9gzA9b@VhozasfRxUhA9rh2237M4izwhuprkY@XFyA6ypdCvICb7ZIG3GtImb1dL3K7bcZZk3WtRwexmr7bxyMqXyZmzdibDyVz6WDWiDSznkk3@Czg57@8PW3/vTQ902EE1sn3P4H) )

```perl6
grammar Mathmania-Plus is Mathemania {
  token op:sym<negate> { n }
  token op:sym<abs>    { a }
}

class Calculate-Plus is Calculate {
  method op:sym<negate> ($/) { make &prefix:<-> }
  method op:sym<abs>    ($/) { make &abs }
}
```

Comment: So, for a sub(grammar|class), you don't have to override or extend methods. That's good stuff.

Answer (score 8):

One benefit of splitting your alternatives into a proto and multis is that you can extend it more reliably. You can add multis to the existing proto in a grammar that inherits from the grammar that declares the proto, and you don't need to list all the possible alternatives (which you'd have to do in case a of a single rule).

This means that you can even have multiple independent extensions to the same grammar, for example by mixing in several rules that supply multis for different symbols to match.

This is basically the mechanism that Perl 6 itself uses when you define a custom operator: there are rules for matching the different kinds of operators (like infix, prefix, postfix, ...), and declaring a new operator derives a new grammar from the currently active one, with a multi candidate added for the new operator. A script can import operators from several modules that don't know of each other thanks to the extensibility of proto token mechanism.